# RShiny Error while executing from R Consol

Tags: shiny

I am trying to run Shiny App from R console, I am getting error as shown in below screen shot. Can anyone please help me in this.
[image]

Comment: What happens when you try and install that package, like with  `install.packages("sourcetools")` ?

Comment: @MikeWise , Thanks for your reply. I able to install "sourcetools" but above error is still appearing when I tried to run Shiny app, Alo noticed that "sourcetools" package version is 0.1.2, Is this causing a problem?

Comment: yes. that is what it is complaining about.

Comment: what is the output from your `getOptions("repos")`

Comment: @MikeWise , I able to resolve issue by installing "sourcetools" package using devtools::install_github("kevinushey/sourcetools"), Now Shiny App is executing

Comment: Yes, but you will soon have other similar problems as it looks like you are not updating from an up-to-date repo. You need to fix your repo problem so you always update from the right source.

Comment: @MikeWise , will use up-to-date repo while installing libraries in future

Comment: Just saying. Mine went to the CRAN mirror at "https://cran.rstudio.com/" right away and got version `.../3.4/sourcetools_0.1.6.zip`.